# HttpURLConnection response is incorrect

Tags: java, xml, parsing, httpurlconnection, inputstreamreader

When using this code below to make a get request:

```
private String get(String inurl, Map headers, boolean followredirects) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        URL url = new URL(inurl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(followredirects); 

        // Add headers to request.
        Iterator entries = headers.entrySet().iterator();
        while (entries.hasNext()) {
            Entry thisEntry = (Entry) entries.next();
            Object key = thisEntry.getKey();
            Object value = thisEntry.getValue();
            connection.addRequestProperty((String)key, (String)value);
        }

        // Attempt to parse
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(stream ); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isReader );
        System.out.println(br.readLine());

        // Disconnect
        connection.disconnect();

        return connection.getHeaderField("Location");
}
```

The resulting response is completely nonsensical (e.g ���:ks�6��﯐9�rђ�  e��u�n�qש�v���"uI*�W��s)

However I can see in Wireshark that the response is HTML/XML and nothing like the string above. I've tried a myriad of different methods for parsing the InputStream but I get the same result each time.

Please note: this only happens when it's HTML/XML, plain HTML works.

Why is the response coming back in this format?

Thanks in advance!

=== SOLVED ===

Gah, got it!

The server is compressing the response when it contains XML, so I needed to use GZIPInputStream instead of InputSream.

```
GZIPInputStream stream = new GZIPInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
```

Thanks anyway!

Comment: Which encoding are you using? Note: **Never** use an `InputStreamReader` without specifying an encoding.

Comment: @Kayaman I've tried specifying UTF-8, but that made no difference whatsoever.

Comment: Then you've looked at the wrong wireshark frames. GZip encoded traffic should look like your "nonsense" data.

Answer (score 2):

use an UTF-8 encoding in input stream like below

```
InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Besides, that doesn't look at all like UTF-8. It could be UTF-16.